# How does the Temporary e-mail work?

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp, pop3

How does the Temporary e-mail work ?

Such as :
[http://10minutemail.com](http://10minutemail.com/)

Comment: Well, it creates an email address, then deletes it after some time. What specifically do you want to know?

Answer (score 3):

There is a hamster running in a cage whenever a temporary email is created.

Just kidding :) (though maybe it's true :)

Actually, they have an email server with a program to process catch-all email address, which means all the emails come to their *@10minutemail.com will go through that program. Then, the program will filter & show you emails come to a specific email address, for example: a2492048@10minutemail.com when you go to their website.